# Adding a object arraylist to a text

Tags: java, android-studio, object, arraylist

I have both string and integer data types so I have created an object arrayList to hold them both but have errors when I want to add the object arrayList to a text. Is this not possible to do?
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static  List <Object> hi = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 int converter = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            converter = converter/2;

            if (copper1Pressed && copper2Pressed) {
                convertedCost.setText("Converted cost: " + convert);

                hi.add(editText.getText());
                hi.add(converter);
                editText.setText("");
                String string1 = "Copper";
                String string2 = "Copper";
                for(Object edit : hi){
                    edit = (string1 + " " + myList.get(0) + " = " + string2 + " " + myList.get(1));
                    txtList.setText(edit);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, do not do that. It is bad strategy.
Alternative solution can be

- Converting int to String, if you do not need to know what is the actual type.

The problem with Object variable is, easy to make mistake.

Your problem is **int** is not a class. You cannot store a native variable as object, since int is not extended from Object class. **Integer** however will let you execute your application properly.

Comment: So would I have the arraylist as a interger and the convert it to a string somehow?

Comment: You have declear arraylist as String, convert the integer as string, "somehow"!